# C Programming Debug Assertion Error

Tags: c++, c, windows

Im doing C homework and trying to get this program to run, but I get this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/UUdLB.png]

Can anyone please run this and see if you get the same? (Change the output directory for the text files)

I've been trying for a long time and just cannot do it:

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>

/////////////////
#define SIZE 2
/////////////////

struct Stock
{
    char name[10];
    int numShares;
    float buyShare,currPrice,fees;
    float initCost,currCost,profit;
};

/* Load the data from the keyboard and calculates 
the Initial Cost, Current Cost, and Profit 
for each stock via an array */

void load(struct Stock s[], int n) 
{
    char nameCompare[30] = "Open the bay doors";
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the Stock Name\n");
        printf(">");
        gets(s[i].name);

        /////////////////////////////////////
        if(strncmp (s[i].name,nameCompare,10) == 0)
        {
            printf("\tI'm sorry, Dave, I'm afraid I can't do that\n");
            Sleep(3000);
            exit(1);
        }

        /////////////////////////////////////
        printf("Enter the Number of Shares\n");
        printf(">");
        scanf("%d", &s[i].numShares);
        printf("Enter the Buying Price Per Share\n");
        printf(">");
        scanf("%f", &s[i].buyShare);
        printf("Enter the Current Price Per Share\n");
        printf(">");
        scanf("%f", &s[i].currPrice);
        printf("Enter the Yearly Fees\n");
        printf(">");
        scanf("%f", &s[i].fees);

        s[i].initCost = (float)s[i].numShares * s[i].buyShare;
        s[i].currCost = (float)s[i].numShares * s[i].currPrice;
        s[i].profit = s[i].currCost - s[i].initCost - s[i].fees;
        fflush(stdin);
    }
}

/* Sort the array of structures 
on stock name and print the array 
after the sort is completed */

void sort(struct Stock s[], int n)
{
    Stock t;
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<n-1;j++)
            if(strcmp(s[j].name, s[j+1].name)>0)
            {
                t=s[j];
                s[j]=s[j+1];
                s[j+1]=t;
            }
}

/* Calculate and print the total profit for all of the stocks. 
That is, find the sum of the 5 profits for each stock. In 
addition, find and print out the number of stocks that 
had a positive profit, the number of stocks that had a 
negative profit, and the number of stocks that broke 
even, that is had a profit of $0.00 */

void calc(struct Stock s[],int n)
{
    float total=0;

    int Pos=0;
    int Neg=0;
    int Even=0;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        total +=s[i].profit;
        if (s[i].profit>0)
            ++Pos;
        else if (s[i].profit<0)
            ++Neg;
        else
            ++Even;
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("%d of stocks broke Positive\n",Pos);
    printf("\t%d of stocks broke Negative\n",Neg);
    printf("\t\t%d of stocks broke Even\n",Even);
    printf("\n");
    printf("The Total Trofit is $%f\n", total); //Check output
    printf("\n");
}
//Output of the calc function
void print(struct Stock s[], int n)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
        printf("The stock is %s\n", s[i].name);
        printf("\tWith Initial cost of $%0.2f\n", s[i].initCost);
        printf("\t\tCurrent cost is $%0.2f\n", s[i].currCost);
        printf("\t\t\tAnd your Profit is $%0.2f\n", s[i].profit); //Check output
        printf("\n");
    }
}
//Save the array of structures to a text file.
void savetext(struct Stock s[], int n)
{
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("c:\\cs36\\textfile.txt","w"); 
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        fprintf(f,"%s\n",s[i].name);
        fprintf(f,"%d  %f  %f  %f  %f  %f  %f\n", s[i].numShares, s[i].buyShare, s[i].currPrice, s[i].fees, s[i].initCost, s[i].currCost, s[i].profit);
    }
    fclose(f);
}
//Retrieve and print the text file.
void loadtext(struct Stock s[], int n)
{
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("c:\\cs36\\textfile.txt","r");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        fgets(s[i].name, sizeof(s[i].name), f);
        fscanf(f, "%d%f%f%f%f%f%f\n", &s[i].numShares, &s[i].buyShare, &s[i].currPrice, &s[i].fees, &s[i].initCost, &s[i].currCost, &s[i].profit);
    }
    fclose(f);
}
//Save the array of structures to a binary file.
void savebin(struct Stock s[], int n)
{
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("c:\\cs36\\binfile.bin","wb");
    if(! f)
    { 
        printf("Could not open the file");
        exit(1); 
    }
    else
        fwrite(&s, sizeof(s[10]), n, f);
    fclose(f);
}
//Retrieve and print the binary file.
void loadbin(struct Stock s[], int n)
{
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("c:\\cs36\\binfile.bin","rb");
    if (! f)
    { 
        printf("Could not open the file");
        exit(1); 
    }
    else
        fread(&s, sizeof(s[10]), n, f);
    fclose(f);
}

int main (void)
{
    printf("Hello, Dave\n");
    Stock s[SIZE];
    load (s, SIZE);
    sort (s, SIZE);
    savetext (s, SIZE);
    savebin (s, SIZE);
    print (s, SIZE);
    calc (s, SIZE);
    loadtext (s, SIZE);
    print (s, SIZE);
    loadbin (s, SIZE);
    print (s, SIZE);
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

This is C, using Visual C++ 2008 Express

Comment: In the future, I'd use `getchar()` rather than `system("PAUSE");` then, it'll work on non-winows environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to access the null pointer.So that it will throw this error.

```
    fprintf(f,"%s\n",s[i].name);
```

In these line, s[i] may be null for some cases in your program so you are trying to access the  member variable of the object which is NULL.

So only it is throwing this runtime error.

Comment: in his code, `s[i]` can't be null. His binary file reading algo smashes the stack, invoking undefined behavior. On windows, it happens to zero the array in that call, but on linux, it caused an infinite loop.

Comment: So how do I fix it? Its that particular line (Thats what the debugger states)

Comment: @user1097161 look at my answer, I got your code to run on my machine; the debugger is misleading you because `fread` corrupted the stack.

Comment: I did the *s. Should that fix it? Because i still get that error. Been trying to fix it for 5 days now..... :(

Comment: `*s`? There should be nothing around the s. Look at the first parameter to fread, not the second

Comment: fread(s, sizeof(*s), n, f); AND
fwrite(s, sizeof(*s), n, f);?

Comment: Just wanted to say thank you! It finally worked, and you showed me some new stuff I didn't know about. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You've passed a `NULL` pointer somewhere in a call to `printf`. It's most likely the format string, or a string argument (`%s`).

Hit the debug button, and the visual debugger will show you precisely where in your code the faulty call originates.

Comment: Its this line here, but I dont see whats wrong with it:

       fprintf(f,"%s\n",s[i].name);

Comment: @user1097161: Use the debugger ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 2):

I noticed four main problems:

- you are mixing `scanf` and `gets`. `gets` in particular is a pit, because it'll overrun buffers with no remorse. Generally it's best to choose one or the other. I've found that the most reliable thing is to use `fgets` to scan each line into a static buffer, and parse from there.
- you are calling `fflush(stdin)`. While stream flushing is well-defined for output streams, it's not for input; likely that line is not doing what you expect.
- you're compiling c with a c++ compiler. As a result, you've created code which doesn't really fit in anywhere. Specifically you shorten `struct Stock` to `Stock`, but never `typedef struct Stock Stock;` You also use C++ and C99 style `for` loops, which isn't too big a deal, but `gcc` (the linux compiler) will complain until you feed it some flags.

And the coup de gras! You currently read and write your binary files like so:

```
 fwrite(&s, sizeof(s[10]), n, f);
 fread(&s, sizeof(s[10]), n, f);
```

The problem is that an array passes as a parameter to a function is treated as a pointer, rather than an array. Thus, `&s` gave you the location of the pointer, rather than the address of the array. `fread` then smashed your stack with the contents of the binary file. Changing those lines to

```
fwrite(s, sizeof(*s), n, f); 
fread(s, sizeof(*s), n, f);
```

fixes the major problem.

When working with arrays, you rarely find yourself taking their address, because they *decay* to a pointer to their first element anyway.